# How to change the thousand-separator in ggplot2 for geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-text

I have created a bar plot using ggplot2 and I have labeled the bars with the values they depict. Since these values are rather large, I would like to use thousand separators. But I want to use an inverted comma instead of a regular comma (I already found out how to separate using commas).

I already tried to do it the same way one can change the thousand separators in scale_y_continuous but it didn't work.

I also read that I should use:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(label.income = gsub("\\,","'", scales::comma(income)))
```

But then I always get the following error message: *"Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function""*

This is the data and code I am using:

```
set1 <- read.table(text = "group income
           group1 30500
           group2 29000
           group3 60500
           group4 18000", header=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(set1, aes(x=group, y=income))+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "dodge", fill="#13449f")+
  geom_text(aes(label = income), position = position_dodge(0.9), 
        vjust=1.3, colour = "white", size=5)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 70000, by = 10000), limits = c(0,70000), labels=function(income) format(income, big.mark = "'", scientific = FALSE))
```

How can I have the same thousand separators on the labels in the bars as I have on the y-axis?

Comment: Try `prettyNum`: `set1 <- mutate(set1, label.income = prettyNum(x = income, big.mark = "\'"))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

is that what you want ?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(set1, aes(x=group, y=income))+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "dodge", fill="#13449f")+
  geom_text(aes(label = format(income, big.mark = "'", scientific = FALSE)), position = position_dodge(0.9), 
        vjust=1.3, colour = "white", size=5)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 70000, by = 10000), limits = c(0,70000), labels=function(income) format(income, big.mark = "'", scientific = FALSE))
```

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you very much!! I always just tried using `aes(label=function(income) format(income, big.mark = "'", scientific = FALSE))`